# Show language's names in their own native language using JavaScript with the help of UTF-8?

Tags: javascript, utf-8

For example from the server, I am going to get a response as:

```
{
Language : ["Arabic","Hindi","English"]
}
```

I have to make tabs like:

```
[العربية][हिंदी][English]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What you're asking for is for the *translation of words into other languages*. That's not a *technical* problem or something that can be solved using text encodings. You just need to type in those words.

Comment: i have 100 clients using my GUI ..so ur saying that i have to go and type on their screens these languages huh..?

Comment: *\*facepalm\** Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. `</sarcasm>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no technical measure or anything that has to do with UTF-8 or text encodings in general that help you with *translating words*. UTF-8 is a technical way to enable you to display text at all using a computer; it is not a dictionary or translator.

Just make an object that you use to *change strings*:

```
var langs = {
    'Arabic'  : 'العربية',
    'Hindi'   : 'हिंदी',
    'English' : 'English'
};

var lang = 'Hindi';

alert(langs[lang]);
```

Comment: nice ..but i have to keep track of all those languages possible.is there a better generic way of doing it..like some converters or some?

Comment: @gokul Translating human languages automatically is simply impossible. I mean you can try with google translate but the result is unacceptable for anything else other than some cheap laughs.